# How to accept only one digit after decimal point without round function

Tags: c#

How to accept only one digit after decimal point without round function.
e.g if i enter 1.458 then it can accept only 1.4 .I use datarowtosave to save that value.

Comment: Show your code ...

Comment: I think you can use column.Precision to set the number of precision digits. See the [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.databasemanager.column.precision(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: How about `float.Parse((1.458f).ToString("F1"))`. :D

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Round(thenumberyouwanttoroundgoeshere,1)
```